# Why NCat overs immediately if I call it by Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, netcat

I must to work with NCat stdin-pipe in my python3-script and I decided to use for this `subprocess.Popen`. But even I call this, NCat immediately overs with error code 2 and writes: `Ncat: You must specify a host to connect to. QUITTING.`. My code:

```
import subsubprocess
a = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '--keep-open', '--listen', '8000'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
...
```

I tried to put `localhost` like penultimate argument:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '--keep-open', '--listen', 'localhost', '8000'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

but it gave that one result. In the console and `nc --keep-open --listen 8000`, and `nc --keep-open --listen localhost 8000` work perfect. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, I'm pretty sure, is something I came across recently.  `Popen` doesn't do what you expect when you pass a list of arguments and specify `shell = True`.  It's happiest when the use of these is mutually exclusive.  So instead of:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '--keep-open', '--listen', '8000'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

I would do either:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '--keep-open', '--listen', '8000'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

or:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(['nc --keep-open --listen 8000'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

I did a little digging into the documentation, and I find a few interesting tidbits that confirm what I've always just kinda believed in my gut through experience:

> If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. ... If args
> is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
> additional items will be treated as additional arguments **to the
> shell itself**.

So I guess the extra arguments are being fed to `/bin/sh` rather than `nc` in your case.